# Starting a session from a function

Tags: php, session, authentication, cookies, session-cookies

Here is my code:

**login.php:**

```
require "auth.php";

$correct_username_password = true;
$user_id = 1;

if($correct_username_password == true) {
    startSession($user_id);
}
```

**auth.php:**

```
function startSession($user_id) {
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
    session_start();
    header('Location: https://www.example.com/successpage');
}
```

but my session is not starting. i know its not starting because my `header` to https://www.example.com/successpage is not redirecting. what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do `session_start();` before using `$_SESSION`.

Here is a valid code example:

```
// auth.php:

function startSession($user_id) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
    header('Location: https://www.example.com/successpage');
    exit();
}

// login.php:

require('auth.php');

$correct_username_password = true;
$user_id = 1;

if($correct_username_password == true) {
    startSession($user_id);
}

var_dump($_SESSION);
```

Note: if you don't put an `exit();` after `header('Location: xxx');` the rest of the page will load.